# Content below pinterest style jQuery grid gets cut off/overlaps underneath

Tags: jquery, css

I am using a pinterest style jquery plugin as in this link:

[example link here](http://tiltworld.co.uk/testing/grid/)

and [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rqsp2fzo/)

All works fine on most screen sizes but when i view it on a mobile screen the content below the grid is cut off with the grid above overlapping it like the picture below:

Working:

[image]

Not working (mobile / smaller screens):

[image]

How can this be solved so my content above doesn't overlap?

jquery code to initialise grid:

```
$('#blog-landing').pinterest_grid({
    no_columns: 4,
    padding_x: 10,
    padding_y: 10,
    margin_bottom: 50,
    single_column_breakpoint: 700
});
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest you use a different plugin. That one, for some inexplicable reason, is setting the class on all of those elements hundreds of times a second - even when not scrolling or resizing the window - which is a complete waste of resources.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'll look elsewhere

Comment: I used this one in a project recently... seems to work well: http://www.yconst.com/web/freetile/